# Eject a stubborn disc from a MacBook

Tags: mac

When you have a CD or DVD you can't get out of a Mac, the steps to follow are:

- press eject
- press option-eject
- (optional) hit the eject button within iTunes
- issue the '`drutil eject`' command
- reboot the computer and hold the mouse button (or eject button) down during startup

If the disc still won't eject, particularly from a laptop, what steps do you try next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MacYourself has [a few things to try](http://www.macyourself.com/2009/05/01/the-ultimate-guide-to-ejecting-a-stuck-disc-from-mac-superdrive/)...

I've been able to use the paperclip trick (insert the tip of a paperclip on the right-hand side of the drive) on a Mac mini. The Macbook may have different drives without the paperclip hole, though, I'm not sure.

Comment: Macbook drives still have the release mechinism, just be careful poking a paperclip through the drive slot.

Comment: Thank you -- the business card trick worked, after several attempts.

Comment: Cool! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

Take it to an Apple store for them to deal with :-)

That's part of what we pay the extra money for, right?

Comment: If waranty or Apple care still covers it, true enough.

Comment: I dont think it'll be a question of warranty or AppleCare, they usually do these sort of small jobs without question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also boot into open firmware by holding `command + option + o + f` during boot and then issue an `eject cd` command.  Gets in at a lower level than most any other software solution.

Comment: That's handy.  I imagine it'll only work with Power-PC-based Macs.

Answer (score 1):

Slot loading Mac CD/DVD drives usually have a small micro switch, hidden at one end of the slot.

You need to hit the micro switch with a paper clip, for example, and sometimes reboot to get it to properly eject.  Just one push, and not hard, it is a 'software'/hardware eject button.

Dunno if this is still the case on newer drives.  I do not think it was a Mac innovation, as they buy their drives from generic vendors.

Answer (score 1):

Hold down left click (or only click) while booting. This will force ejection during boot
before the volume is mounted.